# displaying with ptype all C++ data fields (even inherited) in GDB

Tags: linux, c++11, gcc, gdb

In a C++11 program (compiled with [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) on Linux/Debian/x86-64, with `g++ -Og -g3 -Wall -std=c++11 b.cc -o bprog`), when you have a class hierarchy such as in this file `b.cc`:

```
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  class A {
    int a1i;
    double a2d;
  public:
    A(int x, double y) : a1i(x), a2d(y) {};
    ~A() = default;
  };

  class B : public A {
    std::string b1s;
    int b2ii[2];
    std::vector<long> b3vl;
  public:
    B (int x, double y, const char*s, int a, int b)
      : A(x,y), b1s(s), b2ii{a,b},
        b3vl{x,a,b,x+a,a*b} {};
    ~B() = default;
  };

  int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    B bobj {1,2.1,"bname",3,4};
    return 0;
  }
```

and using a recent [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) (i.e. 7.10) I would like to display all the *data* fields (perhaps even the [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) pointer[s], if there is some) of the type. Using the `ptype` command is not extremely helpful (because inherited fields are not displayed):

```
 (gdb) ptype B
  type = class B : public A {
    private:
      std::__cxx11::string b1s;
      int b2ii[2];
      std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > b3vl;

    public:
      B(int, double, const char *, int, int);
      ~B(int);
  }
```

Most of the motivation is that I am interfacing to [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) (or perhaps some other [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library, but probably GCCJIT), and of course a JITing code need to know implementation details like types and offsets of every data field. If you are interested in more details, see [this thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/jit/2013-q4/msg00023.html).

For example, a read access to `bobj.b3vl[i]` should be inlined by the JIT-er, so I need to understand the machine layout ...

I am aware that the fields inside C++ standard containers and strings are implementation specific (but I do know that they don't vary that much, but a tiny bit, in practice)

Do you have any trick or tips to get all that (field name, type, and perhaps offset) information easily thru GDB (including for inherited fields)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this that is built in to gdb.  See [this gdb feature request](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16223).

However, it can be done relatively easily from Python.  If you have the `pahole` gdb command (not part of upstream gdb, but shipped in Fedora at least), that will do the trick (though it seems to generate really ugly output right now).  It will at least show how the code could be written.

Comment: You may also be interested in just using the `pahole` command from the "7 dwarves" project.  Though I don't know how well it works with C++.

Comment: The command `pahole` is in https://packages.debian.org/hu/squeeze/dwarves.  The gdb `pahole.py` can be found in the fedora RPM, see this patch: http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/gdb.git/tree/gdb-archer.patch